# Curl is setting content type as text/javascript even I mentioned in code as text/html

Tags: php, curl, content-type

I am trying to get page content using curl, but content type of the page is set as  text/javascript; even I set it as text/html in the curel call using below call

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Content-type: text/html', 'charset=utf-8'));
```

Url for testing is http://singh.mobi//vishal/curl/proposalform1.php, same code is working fine for other urls, issue is only for this url

Comment: That sets the content-type of the request body. Why do you think it should affect the content-type of the response?

Comment: then how I will change that, response should be in text/html, where is the problem?

Comment: You can't control what response the server will give you from the client.

Comment: only difference is coming in this part of the header http://screencast.com/t/qqYFuVQL1FYP
it is coming fine for other urls

Comment: That's a response header. The server making the response has to send that. `cURL` is a client, it only makes requests.

Comment: You've asked a very narrowly focused question, without any background information about what you are trying to achieve, and it seems to be based on a false premise. You really need to explain more about your problem in the question.

Comment: What I am going to do is:
I need to trigger email from niftyquoter. So I need csrf token no from the form using curl and use that token to trigger email but this page is returning content as js instead of html

Comment: Then you'll have to change niftyquoter to get it to return HTML instead.

Comment: @user3438880 Basically you want to defeat request forgery protection so you can "trigger email" (or password change, or balance transfer) via forged requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, not `CURLOPT_HEADER`, as this accepts only true and false and controls **if** the headers should be sent, not what they contain.

Anyway, this will only change the headers you send, not the one's you receive!

Comment: I need to get content of that page, so How I sort this out?

Comment: You can't change the headers sent by the server, as cURL is only making requests and fetches data.

Comment: so what is the best way to get csrf token from remote site?